# json from mysql (using php) to labels

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json, uilabel

I get json from my mysql:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

...    

json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Log looks like:

```
2017-08-20 23:01:59.726 APP[5005:328063] JSON: (
        {
        Message = "Message text 1...";
        Name = Lucy;
    },
{
        Message = "Message text 2...";
        Name = Jane;
    },
        {
        Message = "Message text 3...";
        Name = Mike;
    }
)
```

This seems to be fine.
Then my app has 2 text labels (1. for name, 2. for message), when name in the name text label (user gives) is equal to "Name" (in json), I'd like to show the "Message" in the message label (specific message for the name).

My piece of code:

```
if ([[json valueForKey:@"Name"] containsObject: nameText.text])
    {
        getMessage.text = [json valueForKey:@"Message"];
    }
```

This doesn't work, it gives me all the messages, not only 1 specific message for the name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
[json enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        if([[obj objectForKey:@"Name"]  isEqual:nameText.text])
            {
                getMessage.text = [obj objectForKey:@"Message"];
            }
}];
```

Perhaps it will help somebody.